# FastReport from Grouped TListView

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, fastreport

I'm just trying to find my way around FastReports for the first time using Delphi XE2.

I want to export the contents of a TListView as Fast Report.

Using frxUserDataSet I have managed to get the columns of the data exported into a report (following the supplied demo)

However the **TListView** information is divided up using **Groups**.

I would like to display these as either the Master Data, or as a Header in the report.

I only seem to be able to trigger the Master Detail once for the data set...

**Update**
On further investigation I've managed to get the groups to repeat by having a separate UserDataSet for the groups linked to the Master Data.  However there seems to be no way to link the Detail Group to the Master Group - so I now have the correct no. of groups, each with the full set of records...

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you simply create a Group Header/Footer in your report on the Group Field in your frxUserDataSet? This would most closely mimic what is being displayed in the listview and will be what your users would expect.

Comment: How would I set the Group to repeat on each change in group? (I can ID when the  group changes in OnGetValue

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "set the Group to repeat on each change in group?". Data on the report is grouped by value, all items of the same group are printed together preceded by an optional header and followed by an optional footer. You can set the group header to repeat on break of page should you so desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is a demo in the FastReports/Demos folder that illustrates exactly what I was trying to do.

Unfortunately this demo is not mentioned in any of the documentation regarding frxUserDataSets

For anyone who wants to build multi-tier reports, using User Data Sets look at the demo in

```
Program Files/FastReports/Demos/MasterDetailUDS
```